# Use Laravel to update columns in a database for all IDs

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5

How do I update all rows in a table (all IDs) at once, with a database query in Laravel? My current controller code is as follows:

```
public function updateSchedule(Request $request, $id)
{
    $timein = $request->input('timeIn');
    $timeout = $request->input('timeOut');

    DB::table('schedules')
        ->where('id', 1)
        ->update(['time_in' => $timein, 'time_out' => $timeout]);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean „all the id”?

Comment: @Daniel i mean i want to update the whole table.

Comment: because right now i have a static id which is only id = 1

Comment: so remove `where` clausule.

Comment: @Daniel , it return null when I refresh the page

Comment: @Daniel , hey sir it does work actually i just got a type thanks btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update the whole table (the WHOLE TABLE), you would do the following (removing the condition that you only want to update matches where id = 1):

```
public function updateSchedule(Request $request, $id)
{
    $timein = $request->input('timeIn');
    $timeout = $request->input('timeOut');

    DB::table('schedules')
        ->update(['time_in' => $timein, 'time_out' => $timeout]);
}
```

If you want to see something afterwards, you either need to return that value, or a view, or a redirect to the prior page.

For example, the following (although it's not good practice to use `back()` as you don't know where they came from. It's better to go to a specific route / url).

```
public function updateSchedule(Request $request, $id)
{
    $timein = $request->input('timeIn');
    $timeout = $request->input('timeOut');

    DB::table('schedules')
        ->update(['time_in' => $timein, 'time_out' => $timeout]);

    return back();
}
```

Comment: thanks i have one more question can you help me i have asked question but can you wait sir? thanks

Comment: I'll keep an eye open.

Comment: here is the link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54319722/laravel-how-to-group-by-data-and-fetch-last-data-that-has-been-inserted)